# MATLAB and NI 2954R

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a Mex file which i want to use to interface with a hardware device called USRP NI2954R. I want to compile the MEX file but there are many errors.

The following is the part where i experience error:

```
#include "mex.h" 

static uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr[] usrp;
static boost :: mutex messages_mutex ;
```

The errors:

```
error C2653: 'uhd' : is not a class or namespace name 
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'usrp' 
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 
error C2133: 'sptr' : unknown size
```

And there are more, generally on similar lines for the boost line of the code

Comment: Please read [ask] and especially [mcve]. Did you write the code, or is it from someone else? If `uhd` is undefined, it means you are missing a header file (`#include` statement).

Comment: @CrisLuengo, The code is from someone else. I do not know what header files are missing and where to get them from,

Comment: The best person to ask is the one that wrote the code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, i'l try asking him. Meanwhile, if someone here can help me with the header files i will be grateful.